# Swift Package Manager not assigning dependencies

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create a package for iOS using Swift Package Manager.

I have a `Package.swift` that looks like this -

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms:  [.iOS(.v12)],
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyPackage", targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/yannickl/AwaitKit", from: "5.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift", from: "2.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyPackage", dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(name: "MyPackageTests", dependencies: ["MyPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

But my project does not build, my classes that reference these dependencies say they do not exist and I also get a warning in Xcode that there are no targets using these dependencies.

I tried to update `targets` as follows -

```
     targets: [
            .target(name: "MyPackage", dependencies: ["AwaitKit","KeychainAccess","OAuthSwift"]),
            .testTarget(name: "MyPackageTests", dependencies: ["MyPackage"]),
        ]
```

But this made no difference?

Comment: That looks correct, are you sure your project files are assigned to the correct targets?

Comment: It was a silly mistake, thank you